# dropdownlist in mvc _layout file in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, layout, asp.net-mvc-5

In my application i have a form with dropdownlist in _layout file.

After submitting form in View (I have many Views with same _Layout file) goto some Other controller view.

But i am getting always a error

Object reference not set to an instance of an object at dropdownlist.

**My _HomeLayout.cshtml**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Allpost", "User", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "frmEmp" }))
       {
          @Html.Partial("_AllCategories", Model)
        }
```

**Partial View**

```
@model Models.HomePageSearchVM

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.catlist, Model.CategoriesList, "Select Categorie")
```

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult _AllCategories()
        {
            HomePageSearchVM pasvm = new HomePageSearchVM();

            pasvm.CategoriesList = new MultiSelectList(db.CategoriesList, "CatId", "CategorieName");
                return PartialView("_AllCategories", pasvm);
        }
```

**HomePageSearchVM.cs**

```
namespace Entities
{
    public partial class HomePageSearchVM
    {
        public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoriesList { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string[] catlist { get; set; }

        public string search { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View Home**

```
@model Models.PostallVM
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
}
----- some code ----
```

Error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How use **Form** in _Layout file with some text and dropdown fields and call a model in Layout. I am using the same layout file for many Views with different Models.

I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Looks like CategoriesList  is null, Can you try initializing CategoriesList ?

Comment: CategoriesList coming from DB it is ok there is some data in DB i checked.

Comment: am referring to this variable, pasvm.CategoriesList

Comment: Can you provide more information about the View structure?  You are using a Home cshtml view which is expecting a  using a PostallVM model and uses the _HomeLayout which expects a Models.HomePageSearchVM model. The _AllCategories actionis never called right? @Html.Partial("_AllCategories", Model) is not calling the action. It just renderis the partial view. Maybe I am missing something.